# Which Star Trek: The Animated Series episode deals with cyclic universe?

Tags: star-trek, episode-identification, star-trek-tas

I recall from decades ago that one of the cartoon Star Trek episodes had Kirk meeting a version of himself from a previous cycle of the universe.  The universe was suppose to be cyclical, oscillating between expansion and collapse, with the big bang being the transition from collapse to expansion.

I browsed the episode synopses on Wikipedia, but none seem to correspond.  Can anyone recall which episode this was?

Answer (score 4):

The character of James Kirk only encountered "himself" on four occasions;

- [**'TOS: The Enemy Within'**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Enemy_Within_(episode)) in which a transporter accident splits Kirk into 'Good Kirk' and 'Evil Kirk' before being reintegrated by transporter.
- [**'TOS: What Are Little Girls Made Of?'**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/What_Are_Little_Girls_Made_Of%3F_(episode)) where a sophisticated Kirk android is created and then destroyed.
- [**'Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country'**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_VI:_The_Undiscovered_Country) in which a shapeshifting alien briefly impersonates Kirk before being disintegrated.
- ['**TOS: Mirror, Mirror**'](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror,_Mirror_(episode)) featured an "Evil" version of Kirk from a *mirror universe*. At the end, this character was returned to his proper place.

For the record, there are **no instances of him being duplicated in the Animated Series,** none of the TV episodes dealt with a cyclical universe, nor is the 'cyclical universe' itself a feature of the Star Trek fictional universe which would strongly suggest that this wasn't a trek episode.

---

As an aside, although Star Trek usually subscribes to the "[Big-Bang, Big-Crunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang)" theory, the episode [**TAS: The Magicks of Megas-Tu**](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/TAS009.htm) dealt with another theory of universe creation, that of the [Steady State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady_State_theory).

> **Kirk:** *Captain's log, stardate 1254.4. For years scientists have theorised that if our galaxy was created from a great explosion, then
>   the centre of the galaxy might still be creating new matter. The
>   Enterprise is now on a science mission to investigate.*

Comment: I have no idea about Star Trek, but it appears to me that OP is asking about animated, not the original series.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - See edit. He's not thinking of Star Trek unless I'm very much mistaken.

Comment: But the question doesn't ask about duplication, it says "version from another universe"

Comment: Correct.  And the question was about the cartoon series.

Comment: @user2153235 - No episode of the cartoon series matches your description, as I've noted.

Comment: Could it have been a comic?  Easy to confuse a comic in your memory with a cartoon.

Comment: No.. I didn't read Star Trek comics.  I wonder if a cartoon episode could have been lost over the decades.  My memory of the episode is not uncertain, though like anyone else's, it is fallible.

Comment: @user2153235 - I can assure you that no canon episode of Star Trek has been lost.